# Include/exclude defined frames in Beamer

Tags: include, latex, beamer

I have a large Beamer file with many frames. Based on the presentation purpose, I want to include/exclude certain slides from the presentation. Is there a way to define the frames at the end of the document and call them up when wanted? Something like the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

% including the frames
\include{F1}
\include{F2}
% \include{F3}
\include{F4}


% frame definitions
\begin{frame}[F1]
1
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[F2]
2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[F3]
3
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[F4]
4
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I know that I can go frame by frame and add `<beamer:0>` to exclude that frame, but since the presentation is too long it would be great if I had the possibility to do as above.

Comment: Please use the [tex SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for questions about LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what the `\includeonlyframes` command is made for:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\includeonlyframes{%
F1,%
F2,%
%F3,%
F4,%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=F1]
1
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=F2]
2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=F3]
3
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=F4]
4
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really consider the following very pretty, but you could define a `\newcommand` unique for each frame, where the command simply translates to a single value, `0` (excluded) or `1` (included). E.g.

```
\newcommand{\includeFrameA}{0} % exclude frame
\newcommand{\includeFrameB}{1} % include frame
```

Then, using a help command

```
\newcommand{\includeFrame}[1]{beamer:#1}
```

you can define your frames with the addition of `<\includeFrame{\includeFrameX}>` to the frame environment signature; in so including/excluding the frame depending on the value of `\includeFrameX` as specified in the header of your document.

The following example excludes frames "A" and "C", and the produced presentation includes only two pages, containing "B" and "D", respectively.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\includeFrame}[1]{beamer:#1}

% one command per frame, 0/1 : exclude/include
\newcommand{\includeFrameA}{0}
\newcommand{\includeFrameB}{1}
\newcommand{\includeFrameC}{0}
\newcommand{\includeFrameD}{1}

\begin{document}

% frame definitions
\begin{frame}<\includeFrame{\includeFrameA}>
A
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<\includeFrame{\includeFrameB}>
B
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<\includeFrame{\includeFrameC}>
C
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<\includeFrame{\includeFrameD}>
D
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```